# bootstrap 3 border-radius less mixin gone

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap's `.border-radius()` mixin is [no longer there](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/mixins.less#L102) in version 3.

I am working on converting my codebase and thought of this omission as rather strange. Has `.border-radius` been replaced by some other mixin? Is its use discouraged, and if so why?

Comment: Kinda strange. I wouldn't imagine they would replace it, there's not really any better methods of accomplishing a border radius, and they left the single in there. You could probably just grab an old copy and throw it in your less file if you wanted.

Comment: yes, well fixing it isn't hard. Im more concerned about why it was removed. It seems like it couldn't have been unintentional.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Aha! I have located the answer...

> Remove `.border-radius()` and `.border-*-*-radius mixins`. As only Android
>   2.1, iOS 3.2, and older desktop browsers require a prefixed version, we've removed the base mixin. Since we no longer require prefixes for
>   independent corners, we've dropped those mixins as well. Mixins for a
>   single side, like `.border-left-radius`, are still available.

From **[TWBS Pull 6342](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/6342)**, specifically under LESS changes.

Comment: foregoing backwards compatibility just to be on the bleeding edge doesn't make business sense. must be a developers call on that one.

Answer (score 0):

I did this for a div to get rounded corners. border-radius did not seem to work unless I added  border-collapse before border-radius.

```
border-collapse: initial/inherit worked for me;

border-radius: 10px;
```

hope this helps someone. More info can be found [Here](http://jakegroup.com/blog/using-less-css-with-twitter-bootstrap/) with a more detailed explanation